# Get raster cell values from interactive mouse position

Tags: r, raster

I'm looking for a tool similar to `raster::click` but interactive. I would like to move the mouse on a plotted raster and interactively display the values of the the cell from a stack.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by an "interactive" version of `raster::click`. The `click()` function allows you to "Click on a map (plot) to get values of a Raster* or Spatial* object at that location; and optionally the coordinates and cell number of the location." Are you looking for more than this?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for more than this an tool that can display directly the value of the mouse position.